# Collecting all checkbox (checked) items into Array or ArrayList

Tags: java

I have `ActivityNewGame` which has an `ArrayList` (mPlayerList) with items of type `NewGamePlayerItem`. Each `NewGamePlayerItem` instance contains a checked boolean flag and the player's name. I must collect all checked names within an `Array` or `ArrayList` for later use.

In the following method you can see how the player's list is built and how it gets its items. False is the default value for the checked flag and `getText1()` returns the player's name from other activity name list.

```
private void insertNames() {
        if (ActivityPlayers.mNameList == null) {
            mPlayerList = new ArrayList<>();
        } else {
            mPlayerList = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < ActivityPlayers.mNameList.size(); i++) {
                mPlayerList.add(new NewGamePlayerItem(false, ActivityPlayers.mNameList.get(i).getText1()));
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my Adapter implementation:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final NewGamePlayerViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final NewGamePlayerItem currentItem = mNewGamePlayerList.get(position);

    /** In some cases, this will prevent unwanted situations **/
    holder.mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

    /** If true, checkbox will be selected, else unselected **/
    holder.mCheckBox.setChecked(currentItem.getCheckBox());

    holder.mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            /** set object's last status **/
            currentItem.setSelected(isChecked);
        }
    });

    /** Set name **/
    holder.mName.setText(currentItem.getmText());
}
```

Here is the item:

```
public class NewGamePlayerItem {
    private boolean mCheckBox;
    private String mText;

    public NewGamePlayerItem(boolean checkBox, String text) {
        mCheckBox = checkBox;
        mText = text;
    }

    public boolean getCheckBox() {
        return mCheckBox;
    }

    public String getmText() {
        return mText;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean isSelected) {
        mCheckBox = isSelected;
    }
}
```

So what could I do in order to save all checked items/those names in items into array or arraylist?

Comment: Have you tried something yourself yet?

Comment: Well I'm currently thinking could I do it throught this some how:         public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            /** set object's last status **/
            currentItem.setSelected(isChecked);
        } like if ->its checked add to the arraylist, or something

Comment: Create a new Arraylist for storing names of checked Iterms,  Iterate over the mPlayerList  arraylist, check if NewGamePlayerItem at that position has mCheckBox as true then add it to new arraylist created.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly do something like

```
List<NewGamePlayerItem> checkedItems = new ArrayList<>();
for(NewGamePlayerItem item : mPlayerList)
{
    if(item.getCheckBox())
    {
        checkedItems.add(item);
    }
}
```

That would iterate over all `NewGamePlayerItem` in the list mPlayerList and check if the checkbox is selected, if it is then it adds it to an ArrayList called `checkedItems`. Now `checkedItems` contains a list of all selected items.

You could also then get the names from this list as well.

Or if all you needed was the names then it would be something like

```
List<String> checkedNames = new ArrayList<>();
for(NewGamePlayerItem item : mPlayerList)
{
    if(item.getChecked())
    {
        checkedNames.add(item.getmText());
    }
}
```